# Is text description of MD2 algorithm wrong?

Tags: hash, md2

I'm trying to implement MD2 from scratch of [RFC 1319](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1319). It feels like there is a gap between steps 3.2 & 3.3.

After step 2, the checksum C is appended to the message and never mentioned again. We start 18 rounds of XOR-ing for each block using MD buffer X, which will contain the final result.

But when I look at most MD2 implementations, it looks like the checksum serves as an internal state of the algorithm and being re-calculated during each block processing, e.g. in [this](https://github.com/RustCrypto/hashes/blob/master/md2/src/lib.rs#L85-L90) Rust implementation.

Is it implied somewhere in the description or pseudocode?

Comment: I believe the internal state _is_ re-calculated for each block. It is designed similarly to RC4 in that respect.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm just trying to understand, why this important thing is not mentioned in the text description of RFC. Do I miss something between the lines (e.g. because of language barrier) or it's also unobvious native speakers?